# Android - Run response call in main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to make downloader, which download data and then call function in UI thread. I have this in main activity

```
onCreate(){ 
    ...
    dataRepository.downloadIfNewOrEmpty(new DownloadResponse() {
        @Override
        public void SuccessResponse(Response response) {
            // do something in UI
        }
    });
}
```

My function `downloadIfNewOrEmpty` looks for now only simple with sleep()

```
public void downloadIfNewOrEmpty(final DownloadResponse response){
    //final Handler handler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                response.SuccessResponse(ResponseCode.SUCCESS);
                /*handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        response.SuccessResponse(ResponseCode.SUCCESS);
                    }
                });*/
            }catch (Exception e){
                // Log...
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

If I run this code, it normally does the job and update my UI. I found this solution with Handler (android.os.Handler) but if I run it without or with Handler (commented version) it works same.

Although without handler function `SuccessResponse` is run in UI thread?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Although without handler function SuccessResponse is run in UI thread?

Yes, because `response` is instance of `DownloadResponse` which is passed from UI Thread as parameter to `downloadIfNewOrEmpty`.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me a lot's of time.